# What is my Active Directory site?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Is there a quick way to discover what Active Directory site the current server you are logged into is? I googled but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sites are determined by subnet in CIDR notation in the Sites and Services snap-in. You could just take a screenshot of the configuration and by your IP address, determine what site it should be in. Now, if you're looking for a command that shows the CURRENT site try the gpresult command line tool. I'm almost positive that will print it out for you.

Comment: double checked it, this will answer your question!

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in an administrator command prompt:

```
gpresult  /R /Scope Computer
```

Example output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>gpresult  /R /Scope Computer

Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001

Created On 4/23/2012 at 6:34:45 PM


RSOP data for GB7\- on GB7 : Logging Mode
------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Standalone Workstation
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\-
Connected over a slow link?: No
```

Another option would be to use [Nltest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786478%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
Nltest.exe /dsgetsite
```

For more details including all applied Group Policy Objects (GPO) run the following commands:

```
gpresult  /V /Scope Computer
gpresult  /V /Scope User
```

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt, run SET.

You'll get a listing of USERDOMAIN and USERDNSDOMAIN.